# How do I display and print raw HTML on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, html, printing, webview

I have a java application that I'm porting over to android. One function I have is to export a summary of the data to HTML that is displayed in the local browser. How would I mimic this functionality on the Android platform? The intention is to allow the user to view the data easily and save/export/print as they want to.

Here's my regular desktop Java version:

```
String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">.pagebreak {page-break-after: always;}.smallFont{font-size:10px}" + fancyCss + "</style>" + internationalCharacters + "</head><body>" + content + "</body></html>";

try {
    File file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".html");

    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

    stream.write(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: use a WebView..

Comment: start here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer is to use a webview.

include a webview in your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/print_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<Button
    android:text="Print"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/print_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can set html code to the webview in your java class.

```
String html = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>";
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";

final WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);

Button printButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.print_button);
printButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        createWebPrintJob(myWebView);
    }
});
```

And use following method to do the print job

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter =
                null;
        printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("MyDocument");
        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";

        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Print job has been canceled! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

NOTE : the above method is working only on the diveces with Lollipop or later. Anyway you can save your webview as a bitmap if you want.
The code is tested and working. Hope this helps you

Comment: Finally got around to doing this. So, technically, yes it displays the HTML as requested. My problem now is that the webview has zero functionality. I was hoping for some standard browser stuff like Print at least. Is that available? Or can I just push the html to the standard browser?

Comment: @Chris.Brown.SPE you can print the webview. please look at the updated answer. as well as you can save it as an image by captering webview as a bitmap